# Increase attribute value in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to change elements coordinates according some difference value. Say I have bunch of lines to update on drag. On drag event I call this function :

```
var updatePosition = function(dx, dy) {         

    thiz.self.select('line').attr('x2', * wanna increase x2 by dx * ).attr('y2', * wanna increase y2 by dy * );
};
```

Is there an elegant way to do this? Or any way that works :)

Thanks.

UPDATE :

There is FEW lines which position I need to change, so I can't just grab current (x2, y2) and add a new value to it. At least I do not know how.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your selection only has one element in it, you can use `attr` as a getter:

```
var line = thiz.self.select('line');
var x = line.attr('x2');
var y = line.attr('y2');
line.attr('x2', x + dx).attr('y2', y + dy);
```

Although, I am wondering how your drag pattern ended up requiring `thiz.self.select('line');`. I would have expected the drag event to change the *data* which then informs the normal d3 update pattern how to change the line elements. Something kind of like this:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on("dragstart", function(d, i) {
    d.origin = [d.x, d.y];
  })
  .on("drag", function(d, i) {
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy;
    draw(d3.select(this));
  })

function draw(selection) {
  selection
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
}
```

Comment: the problem is that there is few lines I want to move in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out, you were right guys (+1 for your help), the trick is to get this current value, which one can retrieve in a anonymous function like this :

```
var updatePosition = function(dx, dy) {           
    thiz.self.select('line').attr('x2', function(d, i) {
        return d3.select(this).attr('x2') - dx;
    }).attr('y2', function(d, i) {
        return d3.select(this).attr('y2') - yx;
    });
};
```

So `this` in this case will point to the line itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just translate the positions like so :

```
d3.select(selection).attr('transform', 'translate(' + valueX + ',' + valueY + ')');
```

So in your case :

```
var updatePosition = function(dx, dy) {         
    d3.select(selection).attr('translate', 'translate(' + dx+ ',' + dy+ ')');
};
```

EDIT

As you only want to move `x2` and `y2` do the following :

```
var updatePosition = function(dx, dy) {         
   d3.select(selection).attr('transform', function(d)//selection being your element you wish to edit
   {
     return 'translate(' + (d.x2 + dx) + ',' + (d.y2 + dy) + ')');
   }
};
```

Comment: I do not need to move whole line, I need to move x2, y2 coordinates only.

Comment: @Anton i know you have found the answer, but I obviously misinterpreted the question. I have updated my answer